# Laravel 4.2 with Stripe recurring payment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, stripe-payments

I'm using `laravel 4.2`.

I want to use `Stripe` payment gateway for `recurring Pro-rated payments`. I've subscribed with Stripe.

The `API` in `Stripe` seems in `PHP`. I want to use it with `laravel 4.2` hence is there any ready made package I can use for?

As I am using `recurring pro-rated payments`, it is necessary to me the package should support all the methods of recurring payments on stripe.

Can anyone suggest me the best one?

I've searched on `Packagist` but the packages have not proper documented for recurring payments.

Comment: I'm not sure if it totally fits your needs but have you looked at Laravel Cashier? It's part of the fraemwork: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/billing. This may also be of interest to you: http://easyecommercebook.com/

Comment: There is no details regarding recurring payment in Laravel cashier. I think https://packagist.org/packages/cartalyst/stripe will be better, it is also well documented.

Comment: Recurring payment = Subscription. See here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/billing#subscribing-to-a-plan. Laravel Cashier is written by Taylor Otwell himself I think, so I'd give it some consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel Catalyst  here is the link https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe-laravel/1.0
It help for recurring payments.